# Pearson correlation coefficient after transformation

Tags: probability, correlation, pearson-r

For two random variables $X$ and $Y$, if I know the Pearson correlation coefficient $r=\mbox{Corr}(X,Y)$, is there a general way to obtain the correlation between $F(X)$ and $G(Y)$?

Any assumption, for example, c.d.f. of $X$ and $Y$ and the properties about $F(\cdot)$ and $G(\cdot)$, can be added if necessary.

Or if someone provides me some related literatures, I will appreciate it.

Comment: Not in complete generality. The correlation between $a + bY$ and $c + dX$ is identical to the correlation between $Y$ and $X$ so long as $b$ and $d$ have the same sign and its negation if $b$ and $d$ have different signs. Necessarily neither coefficient can be zero.

Comment: The best way to see this is to think in terms of a scatter plot. Changing the values at axis ticks by a linear transformation at most changes the sign of the correlation, but warping the data will usually change the correlation too. Think of changing temperature scales or the units of height or weight.

Comment: Think the other way round. I tell you that a correlation is 0.42. You need the data too to tell me what happens if one variable is say logged or rooted.

Comment: Pearson correlation coefficient is invariant under linear transformation. To other transformation, can we calculate it?

Comment: Not quite: as said, the sign can change. In general, the only calculation is to go back to the data. For example suppose some data are such that $x > 0, y > 0, y = a + bx$ exactly so the correlation is $1$. Now take logarithms of both variables. In general the correlation is no longer $1$ but what it is depends on the data. (Exceptionally, it could be $1$ with just two distinct data points.)